# SSH: Permission denied, please try again. While tryng to connect to remote 12.04 server

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, password, vnc

I'm having quite the head ache because of this.

The day before yesterday I rented a VPS at [atlantic](http://www.atlantic.net/cloud-hosting/cloud-servers/). They provided me with vnc and root's ssh credentials.

I could only login through a VNC viewer applet they've in their control panel website. But whenever I tried to connect using ssh with the credential they provided for root user. I kept getting a horrible `Permission denied, please try again`. Ok, no problem, I kindda remembered something about root account being disabled in Ubuntu (although why I could log using root credentials using the host's VNC, I prefered think about it as a universal mistery), so I logged using vnc, and changed root password. Tried again to ssh it using my new password and... success.

That same night a colleague needed an ssh, so I created the user (yes, through add user). He had the same faith. `Permission denied, please try again` all over again. No problem, I logged through VNC using his account (success) and changed password. Tried again to ssh using the new user's password and... success!

It was a good night.

Next day (today) I tried to ssh. No luck. Server kept greeting me with `Permission denied, please try again.`

"Oh it's that again". Well, I tried the procedure that served so well yesterday. Changing password. This time, with no luck.

Through the day I've been able to follow a couple of troubleshooting guide from ask ubuntu. No luck. I just keep getting the same error.

I'm not very good using the command line so, I just don't know how could I post my sshd_config while only connecting through a VNC applet (!!!), but I can tell you I did nothing to it but uncomment the lines

```
ListenAddress ::
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

That's it.

Having not tried being a sysadmin ever before, I'm kindda lost here. I can't even explain myself why would it let me in one day, and the next day deny me access again.

I may be losing something obvious, can someone help me?

#### Update

Ok, so just because why not, I kept trying sshing and changing password. It happened again! After A LOT of tries, after I changed the password for nth time, it worked again. Any ideas?

#### Update 2

After a couple of minutes of having sshed, the terminal displayed "Write failed: Broken pipe" before showing my usual local shell prompt.

Is this any clue about what's happening?

Comment: You really shouldn't allow root access through your ssh server. This is a potential security hole and it is something hackers look for. You should create a new user account and disable root login [How to disable root login](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/security-tip-disable-root-ssh-login-on-linux/)

Comment: That's what I tried, but the other user account suffers from the same problem. I think I'm not really good at explaining myself,

Comment: You should try connecting with a key instead of using password logins

Comment: Do you know any article/blog post where they guide me on how to do it and explain me what is happening behind the curtains? I like knowing what I am doing (I'm a programmer and really don't need a "for dummies" guide, I really want to lear :)

Comment: This is a GREAT tutorial on SSH Keys: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys

Comment: What does `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` say when you try to ssh?

Comment: did we ever see an sshd_config for this, "PasswordAuthentication yes"  confirmed ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what is going on but you should try changing the password using the console. Open a VNC session and open a console. Then enter:

```
passwd
```

You will then be prompted for a new password. Enter a good password and then confirm it. Now restart the server and see if the password sticks. Like I said, you should disable root login to your ssh server. If you want to change the root password, then login to your root account and use the `passwd` command. If you forgot your root password, then enter:

```
sudo passwd
```

This will set the password for the root user. See if that helps your situation.

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear, but I did it and worked a couple of times, but not the other 100 times I tried.